# Dropping a session variable (or the value of one) into a client's local application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to build a system where, when the user logs in to an online ASP.NET site, the User ID (that is placed in a session variable) is then stored on to a local application (c# application) for later use.

So far, the only way I can think of doing this is, when the user logs in, the User ID is stored in a text file on the client's machine. But, this would not be an ideal solution, as this means the local client application must then check the file to make sure the contents have not changed (almost every second as it is important that the client Application always has the correct User ID).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What type of C# application?  WinForms?

Comment: At the moment it is just a console application however (as this is still in early development) this can be changed if need be

Answer (score 2):

When you say "the User ID is stored in a text file on the client's machine" I deduce you mean cookies, because you simply can´t store files on client machines via web applications, unless there is some sort of ActiveX control involved.

You can perfectly store a cookie with the User Id on the client and access it with your console app, but this is not very reliable, as the user can have cookies disabled or he can clean the cookies folder and also because different browsers use different folders for storing cookies.

So my choice would rather be a storing the current logged users in a database and make the console app poll that info through a WCF service.

If you don´t want to use a Database, store an XML file on the server that could act as your database and use for example LINQ to XML to retrieve the data via that WCF service.

Other option we can equate instead of polling the info you could use WCF Duplex Services and make the WebService push that info to the client apps once a user logs in.

Comment: I have thought about using a database but this is still not an ideal solution as it has the same draw backs in that it does not give real time feed back Unless it is being querryed every second by a webservice which is not the way I really want to do this but it looks like thats gonna be how this is done, thanks for your comment